# Size of firestore rules path

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use the size of the path in the firestore rules, but can't get anything to work, and can't find any reference in the firestore docs on how to do this.

I want to use the last collection name as a parameter in the rule, so tried this:

```
match test/{document=**}
   allow read, write: if document[document.size() - 2] == 'subpath';
```

But .size() does not seem to work, neither does .length

Comment: Hello ! Did you achieve to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done but you first have to coerce the Path to a String.

To get the Path of the current resource, you can use the `__name__` property.

[https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource#**name**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource#__name__)

For reference, `resource` is a general property that is available on every request that represents the Firestore Document being read or written.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource

```
resource['__name__']
```

The value returned by `__name__` is a Path, which is lacking in useful methods, so before you can use `size` you will need to coerce the Path to a String.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String.html

```
string(resource['__name__'])
```

Once converted to a string, you can then `split` the string on the `/` operator and convert it into a `List` of String path parts.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String.html#split

```
string(resource['__name__']).split('/')
```

Now you can retrieve the size of the List using the List's `size` method.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#size

```
string(resource['__name__']).split('/').size()
```

One of the challenging things about Firestore rules is that there's no support for variables so you often will repeat code when you need to use a result more than once. For instance, in this case, we need to use the result of the split twice but cannot store it into a variable.

```
string(resource['__name__']).split('/')[string(resource['__name__']).split('/').size() - 2]
```

You can DRY this up a bit by making use of functions and using the parameter as your variable.

```
function getSecondToLastPathPart(pathParts) {
  return pathParts[pathParts.size() - 2];
}

getSecondToLastPathPart(string(resource['__name__']).split('/'))
```

Tying it all together for your solution, it would look like this...

```
function getSecondToLastPathPart(pathParts) {
  return pathParts[pathParts.size() - 2];
}

match test/{document=**} {
   allow read, write: if getSecondToLastPathPart(string(resource['__name__']).split('/')) == 'subpath';
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: string does not accept 'path' as an input

Comment: So, I tried version 1 and 2 of firestore rules, and every combination... this simply does not work... maybe it used to, but not anymore

Answer (score 1):

You can learn rules [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#string)

```
   // Allow reads of documents that begin with 'abcdef'
   match /{document} {
      allow read: if document[0:6] == 'abcdef';
   }
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem i'm having. I'm using a multisegment wildcard  `{document=**}`. Which I have managed to find out that it is constructed of multiple pahts so you can do document[0] to get out the first path argument. But I want to get out the second to last path parameter `document[document.size() - 2]`, so need to know the size of the multisegment wildcard path, but `.size()` does not work