# How to Get Data From Request Path in Firestore Rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to figure out how to get an array from the path on an `update` or `create` in order to create validators based on the path data:

```js
function test() {

  // option 1
  return string(request.path).split('/')[0] == 'databases';

  // option 2
  // return string(request.resource.__name__).split('/')[0] == 'databases';
}

match /posts/{document} {
  allow update: if test();
  ...
}
```

I have tried both of the previous examples with `request.resource.__name__` and `request.path`... How do I parse the data out of the requested path?

Thanks,

J

Comment: What specifically are you trying to get from path?

Comment: I'm trying to convert it to an array to get any value... like in this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49193264/size-of-firestore-rules-path, which does not work

Comment: specifically I want to get the last 2 values of the array

Answer (score 5):

Lets assume this is my request.path `/databases/%28default%29/documents/posts/123456`.

```
function test(docId) {
  // request.path supports map access.
  return request.path[4] == '123456'; // this will return true;
  return request.path[3] == 'posts'; // this will return true;
  return docId == '123456'; // this will return true;
}
match /posts/{documentId} {
  allow update: if test(documentId);
}
```

So if your path has 5 segments, `request.path[4]` && `request.path[3]` will return the last 2 segments.

Comment: this only helps me if I know the number of segments, I want to get the "last 2" segments... ex, a subcollection

Comment: For a subcollection, you use rules like this `match /{path=**}/batch/{batchId} {allow read: if true);}`. In this case, the last 2 segments are `batch` and `batchId`.

Comment: Is this not possible with `request.path` or `request.resource.__name__` ? I feel like this is work around.

Comment: the problem is that `request.path` and `request.resource['__name__']` are `path` not string. So, you can convert it to string or easily manipulate it.

Comment: When I convert them using `string(...)`, it does not work correctly (like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59829951/271450) claims).  Have you gotten this to work? I am wondering if that only works in version 1 and not 2 of Firestore Rules?

Comment: Yeah, string(‘…’) didn’t work on my end either. Maybe it only works on version 1.

Answer (score 0):

So, there is not way to ultimately change these `path` variables into an array or string that I can find:

- request.resource.**name**
- request.path
- resource.**name**
- any `path()` type

We need to change them into an array, to get their size. We need to get their size, to get the last few values. This would obviously be useful for universal functions that work on any number of sub-collections where you don't have to manually define the variable in the `match`.

Other posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49193264/size-of-firestore-rules-path) state that once upon a time ago, you could *cast* the data type to a `string()` like `string(request.path)`, but this no longer works.

You could do something like this:

```js
function doSomething() {
  return (request.path[4] && something1())
  || (request.path[6] && something2())
}
```

Of course, you don't want to do this for 5 levels of sub-collections. Ultimately, you just can't have a universal function without defining the variables before.

Perhaps [Frank Van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) can get the `size()` function or the `toString()` function added to the path variable.

J